# how to avoid this double 'for' loop in R

Tags: r

I have to perform function on all combinations of columns of a data frame ddf. I normally do it with:

```
myfunction <- function(col1, col2) {print(aov(col1~col2))}
ddf = data.frame(first=1:3, second=letters[1:3], third=LETTERS[1:3])

len = length(ddf)
for(i in 1:len) for(j in 1:len) myfunction(ddf[,i], ddf[,j])
[1] "1 1"
[1] "1 a"
[1] "1 A"
[1] "a 1"
[1] "a a"
[1] "a A"
[1] "A 1"
[1] "A a"
[1] "A A"
```

How can I avoid using 'for' loop in this situation? I tried apply but it takes only one column at a time:

```
apply(ddf, 2, myfunction)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `outer` with a vectorized version of your function using `mapply`.

```
id <- seq_along(colnames(ddf))
outer(id,id,function(x,y)mapply(myfunction,ddf[,x],ddf[,y]))
```

Answer (score 2):

agstudy's option is great. Another option is to generate the iteration map beforehand and then use apply on this:

```
iterate <- expand.grid(1:3,1:3)
X <- apply(iterate,1,function(x) myfunction(ddf[,x[1]],ddf[,x[2]]))
```

It's probably worth going down this route only if you have a seriously large number of columns and a multi-core system. Then you would parallelise it using one of the parallel apply operations in the `parallel` package.